# Best practice for integration testing in React Redux app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-testing-library

I'm trying to set up tests for a React-Redux application. Most resources including [Redux Docs](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests), and [the main contributor to react-testing-library](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/testing-implementation-details) argues for a focus on integration tests and that the Redux code as far as possible should be considered an implementation detail. That's cool and all, but I'm struggling to do this in practice.

Most examples I've found on integration testing sets up a component where you can observe the effect in the immediate unit. But several places in my app, I have components that send dispatches to my store which causes a re-render in another part of the app. To illustrate my question, I've made a simplified component tree below where I want to click the `AddToListButton` to cause `Element1` to be added to the `List`.

If Redux is an implementation detail, how do I actually test that clicking the button causes the update without rendering (more or less) the whole app? I understand how to do unit-testing and end-to-end testing, but not sure how I would implement integration testing.

```
<App>
  <Search>
    <SearchResult>
      <Element1>
        <AddToListButton /> //I WANT TO TEST THIS BUTTON
      </Element1>
      <Element2>
        <AddToListButton />
      </Element2> 
    </SearchResult>
  </Search>
  <List>
    <Element1 /> // WHEN THE BUTTON IS PRESSED THE ELEMENT SHOULD GO HERE
  </List>
</App>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would actually render (more or less) the whole app - or at least all involved components. That is pretty much the point of integration testing.

The only difference to end-to-end testing is that no other services are involved and you *can* also integration-test only parts of your app, but that does not mean that you *have* to integration-test only parts of your app.